# Issue while adding Lead to Salesforce campaign in SFMC journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am facing an issue while working on a Journey which takes user inputs from Landing page and creates Lead in Salesforce. The lead is created successfully but the issue is while assigning Lead to Campaign. I have tried the following:

1. While mapping Lead fields, I am assigning Primary Lead Source as the Campaign I want to add
2. Added a Campaign Member activity in the Journey, and selected the campaign

None of these options are adding Lead to Campaign in Salesforce so please suggest if there's anything else I should try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I added a wait by duration of 15 mins between Lead and Campaign Member activity in Journey.

Wait by duration was set to 15 mins as the Poll sync for MC connect is 15 mins. Lead is being added to Campaign in Salesforce now.